# How to append csv file in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Wanted to insert multiple rows into single csv file stored in s3 bucket. Each post form data should be saved in the same csv file in s3 bucket in a new row.Currently, new entry is saving as an individual file.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var name = event.name
    var phonenumber = event.phonenumber
    var email = event.email
    var gender = event.gender
    var message = event.message
    var region = event.region
    var favfood = event.favfood

    var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000);
    var filename = "phase1_" + timestamp + ".csv"

    fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/" + filename, name+ ',' +phonenumber+ ',' +email+ ',' +gender+ ',' +message+ ',' +region+ ',' +favfood);
    var body = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/" + filename);
    // var base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');
    s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: 'mybucket',
                    Key: filename,
                    Body:body,
                    ACL: 'public-read-write'
                  },function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                   console.log(err.message);
                        }
                  console.log('Successfully uploaded file.');

                    });



};
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately You can not append to object in S3 , Please [Refer this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395).

**Once an object has been uploaded, there is no way to modify it in place;** your only option is to upload a new object to replace it, which doesn't meet your requirements.

> You could have entries sent to a SQS queue and when the queue size
>   reaches a set number, you could have the log messages batched together
>   and added as an object in your S3 bucket. This still won't satisfy
>   your requirement of appending to a single object.